# Downloading Media Creation Tool in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, windows, wine, browser

I don't have any device with Windows 10 installer and I need to download media creation tool. I entered [Windows 10 download site](https://www.microsoft.com/tr-tr/software-download/windows10) of Microsoft, It shows me only ISO file to download. I searched for media creation tool in Google ( Maybe Microsoft has subpage for downloading it. ) but all results are from [other web sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=media%20creatioon%20tool%20windows&oq=media&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l3j46i175i199j0j69i60.3813j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I can't trust these web sites ( Maybe they will download media creation tool that install patched / edited Windows ( Not original ). ). Is there a way to download it from original source? I tried ISO file so much but it is not working on my computer. ISO file is not booting but when I directly write Windows to my USB Stick with media creation tools, it works.

I'm not asking how to create a Windows 10 bootable USB, I'm asking for how to download media creation tool, I need it.

Comment: I don't see why ISO file is not good for you and how the question is related to Ubuntu.

Comment: ISO file is not working on my device.

Comment: How do you expect to be "working"? It is an image file. It can be mounted on Ubuntu, or burnt to some media. And how all that is related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Because I’m using Ubuntu and asking it to how to download to Ubuntu. I’ll use WINE.

Comment: I clicked the link and see that it is a Windows installer. You can't use it in wine.

Comment: Why? I heard that WINE only can’t execute UWP / WPF executables.

Comment: @Pilot6 no, because I know how to create bootable USB. I almost changed operating systems 5 and more times. But with ISO file, it doesn’t boots.

Comment: There is no Windows installer "executable".

Comment: Yes, there is. Media creation tool. Didn’t you heard anything about it?

Comment: I gave you a link to a manual how to create a Windows USB stick properly on Ubuntu.

Comment: As I said, it is not working. I already tried it this morning.

Comment: Would use WoeUSB or MkUSB to make Windows bootable.  Have you checked that the ISO and/or USB are good.  Media creation tool is for Windows OS.  Seems to be more work trying to fake Microsoft thinking you are on Windows, trying to get it to work with wine and then trying to make a USB that works.

Comment: Ok, I’ll just install Ubuntu. I noticed that GNOME is better than Windows’s “Fluent” design.

Comment: By the way my question only was about downloading Media Creation Tool, it wasn’t too hard I think. Probably I should show my computer as a Windows computer to browser but I dont how to do it and how to Google it ( My English is bad. ).